# React.JS plugin for Wordpress embedded widget and a full-screen container

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am building a React.JS plugin for Wordpress.

I was able to build the wrapper that combined Wordpress with React.JS and embed my widget using a shortcode.

Currently, the app code is like the below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const targets = document.querySelectorAll('.smw-root');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(targets, target => {
  const id = target.dataset.id;
  const settings = window.smwSettings && window.smwSettings[id];
  ReactDOM.render(<App settings={settings} />, target);
});
reportWebVitals();
```

The `<App />` piece above is a product list. It shows up fine. I had to add `"homepage": "/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/widget/build",` to package.json and it worked fine.

In addition to the list, my plugin also has to render a full-screen container with product details, displayed when one of the entries in the above list is clicked.

I would like this "item details" route to be formatted as `/item/:id`. If possible, I would also like website administrators to control the look of this "item details" container to the extend that webmasters would select styles, background, header, and footer, etc. I would best prefer then have product details be embedded with something similar to shortcodes per attribute, e.g. [smw-attribute type="image"] and [smw-attribute type="description"] or [smw-attribute type="manufacturer"].

If embedding individual "properties" is difficult, I would go with just a full-screen container.

Currently, I have the wrapper and `enqueue` and `shortcode` php pieces. Enqueue part adds the necessary styles and scripts to the HTML page, while shortcode returns an empty div for the right class and a unique id, so multiple widgets could be embedded into the same page, if necessary.

How do I add the product details route to Wordpress and my React.JS plugin, so the details page is rendered whenever a visitor clicked on the product link from the list, and/or accessed it using a direct link?